# Web.Config Transformation Not Working

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, web.config-transform

Using VS 2k15, ASP.NET 4.5
My Transform is not working.  I was looking in preview and the files are the same.  Then I figured maybe I had to deploy to see transformation.  So I set up a custom Deploy to my desktop, using the Deploy Configuration.  Checked the web.config after publishing that, still matching the original.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

I know when I do the preview I get a warning at the top of the preview that says..."

```
These files have different encodings. Left file: Unicode (UTF-8) without signature. Right file: Unicode (UTF-8) with signature. You can resolve the difference by saving the right file with the encoding Unicode (UTF-8) without signature.
```

However, when I choose Save Options and save the Deploy file with no signature (so they're matching) the message still comes up.  Just not sure what's going on.  Any ideas why I can't this transform to work?

Web.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">

  <appSettings>
      <add key="fileLibrary" value="c:\vsoProjects\localFiles\rlFileLibrary" />
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="appConnString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb);Initial Catalog=DevDB;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=300" />
  </connectionStrings>

</configuration>
```

Web.ContDeploy.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">

  <appSettings>
      <add key="fileLibrary" value="R:\rlFileLibrary" xdt:Transform="Replace" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>

  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="appConnString" connectionString="Data Source=myserver.test.com;Initial Catalog=DeployDB;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Connect Timeout=300" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes(connectionString)" xdt:Locator="Match(name)"/>
  </connectionStrings>

  <system.web>
      <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />    
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your Configuration Manager window?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert on the transform, but my (working) transform for the appSettings key has this signature:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="datafolder" value="D:\sites\removedpath\App_Data\" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)"/>
  </appSettings>
```

which is slightly different than yours

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.  This project was converted a while back from asp.net 2.x to 4.5.

The web.config still had an attribute up in the configuration section.

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
...
</configuration>
```

You can see it up top in the code I posted.  I didn't realize it was still there.  After all that time banging my head against my desk I just removed that attribute, preview transform, and voila it was there!  Also deploys properly as well.